# LWC My Track list is not rendering after retrieving new data using APEX

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter

I have the following code to retrieve records from APEX and store them in a @track List but it's not rendering somehow. I checked my Apex, its working fine.
Please help where I am doing wrong -

**APEX**

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<OBJ__c> GetObjectRelatedList(string recordID) {
        
        return [SELECT Id, Name, from OBJ__c where Id = :recordID];

    }
```

**JS**
Method to retrieve using APEX and store them into relatedRecords list

```
//DEFINED ON TOP
import GETOBJRELATED from '@salesforce/apex/mapObjectController.GetObjectRelatedList';

//ASSINGED VARIABLES
@track relatedRecords = [];
@api recordId;

    connectedCallback() { //WORKS FINE ON PAGE LOAD or REFRESH
        this.getRelatedRecords();
        
    }

 getRelatedRecords() {
        GETOBJRELATED({ recordID: this.recordId }).then(data => {
            this.relatedRecords = [];
            this.relatedRecords = data;

        }).catch(error => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });

    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <template for:each={relatedRecords} for:item="rec">
                        <tr key={rec.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">

                            <td>
                                <div style="text-align: center;"><strong>{rec.Name}</strong></div>
                            </td>

                                <lightning-button-icon data-id={rec.Id} icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="Remove" onclick={deleteRecords}></lightning-button-icon>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
```

Comment: Since you have marked the apex method as cacheable and the one parameter isn't going to change, the client side will maintain a cache and will only call the server when that cache has expired. Remove the cacheable from the apex and all will be good.

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!!!! IT WAS THAT EASY I SPENT SO MANY DAYS ON THIS TO DEBUG AND FAILED.. YOU ARE a CHAMPION!!!!!!!!!!. Please Add in the answer, I will mark as Answer. Thank you Lukas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have marked the apex method as cacheable, and the one parameter isn't going to change (assuming this is being used on a Lightning Record Page), the client side will maintain a cache of the initial results and will only call the server when that cache has expired.

You call the method imperatively, which means you don't have to have this result set cacheable (unlike with wires).

Remove the cacheable from the apex and all will be good.